# 100% test coverage for a select component

Tags: reactjs, code-coverage, storybook, ts-jest

I'm having trouble achieving 100% test coverage for a select component in my project. I'm using @storybook/testing-library and @storybook/jest for testing. Although my tests are passing, some parts of the code are not being covered. I've attempted to create different tests, but I haven't been successful in getting the desired coverage. and i am getting uncovered line on line 32 >(({ options, testId, ...rest }, ref) =>

```
  export const InputSelect: FC<InputSelectProps> = forwardRef<
  InputSelectProps,
  HTMLSelectElement
>(({ options, testId, ...rest }, ref) =>
  isEmptyNode(options) ? null : (
    <Select data-testid={testId} {...rest} ref={ref}>
      {options?.map((o) => (
        <option key={o.value} value={o.value}>
          {o.children || o.value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
);
```

And here are my stories test cases:

```
    export const Default: Story = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      exclude: ['value', 'rootProps', 'testId', 'aria-errormessage'],
    },
  },
  args: {
    options: [
      { value: 'option1', children: 'Select1' },
      { value: 'option2', children: 'Select2' },
      { value: 'option3', children: 'Select3' },
      { value: 'option4', children: 'Select4' },
      { value: 'option5', children: 'Select5' },
    ],
  },
  render: (args) => (
    <>
      <InputSelect {...args} />
    </>
  ),
};

export const Tests: Story = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      exclude: ['value', 'rootProps', 'testId', 'aria-errormessage'],
    },
  },

  args: {
    ...Default.args,
  },

  render: (args) => (
    <>
      <InputSelect {...args} testId={'with-options'} />
      <InputSelect {...args} options={[]} testId={'without-options'} />
    </>
  ),

  play: async ({ args, canvasElement, step }) => {
    const canvas = within(canvasElement);

    const selectElement = canvas.queryByTestId(
      'with-options'
    ) as HTMLSelectElement;

    await step('The component only renders if it has options', async () => {
      await expect(selectElement).toBeTruthy();
      await expect(canvas.queryByTestId('without-options')).toBeFalsy();
      const renderedOptions = within(selectElement).queryAllByRole('option');
      expect(renderedOptions).toHaveLength(args.options?.length);
    });

    await step('select options correctly', async () => {
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select1');
      expect(selectElement.value).toBe('option1');
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select2');
      expect(selectElement.value).toBe('option2');
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select3');
      expect(selectElement.value).toBe('option3');
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select4');
      expect(selectElement.value).toBe('option4');
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, 'Select5');
      expect(selectElement.value).toBe('option5');
    });
  },
};
```

I have already tried adding tests for the empty options case and the rendering of options. I've also written a test for selecting options using userEvent.selectOptions.

Could you please review my code and provide guidance on how to achieve 100% test coverage for this select component?

Comment: Why do you need 100% code coverage? It is not a good goal. You should ensure you are covering the important pieces of code once. For instance, selecting each of the five options and checking the value every time is redundant unless there is something different among the options or the method of selection.

Comment: In this case i need to do it. Coz this is the assignment to do